# Windows Creating tmp Files When Rotating Images

Tags: windows-server-2016, image, tmp

Windows server 2016 Standard

Client PC's Windows 2010 Enterprise 2019

We have a shared folder that contains images (jpgs), we've noticed that when an image is opened in the default windows image viewer (double clicking) and rotated then saved, a new `.TMP` file is created in the same directory. It's named something similar to the original, but the file size is much larger than the original.

Any ideas why this could be happening, maybe it's somehow related to it being a shared folder and used by others simultaneously?

I've noticed [other users have reported a similar issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-store-photo-app-leaving-tmp-files-when/db2dad27-120b-4d6e-aaa3-6d7ef7caa6a9) but I can't find a solution.